# Finding the largest probability of likely event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For any $n\ge 0$, what is the largest possible probability $p$ such that $0$ is the most likely number of successes in $n$ trials, assuming the each trial is independent.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I don't seem to understand what the problem is asking.

Comment: Keyword is: Mode.  That's what they're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Let the random variable $X$ follow a Binomial distribution such that $$Pr\{ X = k\} = \frac{n!}{k!~(n-k)!}p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \qquad \text{giving} \qquad \frac{Pr\{ X = k+1\}}{Pr\{ X = k\}} = \frac{n-k}{k+1}\frac{p}{1-p}$$ which can be used to determine the peak position in general given $\{n,\,p,\, k\}$. The dependence in $p$ itself is not monotone nor is it in $k$.

Here the situation is simple cuz the requirement is $$\frac{Pr\{ X = k+1\}}{Pr\{ X = k\}} < 1 \qquad \text{for} \qquad k \geq 0 \\
\implies \frac{n-k}{k+1}\frac{p}{1-p} < 1 \qquad \implies p < \frac{k+1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}$$
for our case, assuming no ties are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit oddly worded, so I can understand your confusion. It's basically saying (hopefully I can explain it better than it's already written):

You are given a value $n$, which is a strictly positive integer. You are going to have $n$ independent events, each of probability $p$ (i.e. you've got $X \sim Bin(n, p)$ as a binomial distribution), such that the most likely number of successes is 0. That is, $\forall (k > 0)\ Pr(X = k) <= Pr(X = 0)$. What is the largest possible value of $p$?

Comment: I still don't understand. can you add more?

Comment: @user23899 **Hint:** what is the formula for the *mode* of a binomial distribution?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to look at a specific example.  Suppose $n = 3$.  If $p = 0$, then clearly the most likely number of successes is $0$.  If $p = 1/2$, on the other hand, then the binomial theorem yields

$$
P(0) = P(3) = \frac{1}{8}, \qquad P(1) = P(2) = \frac{3}{8}
$$

and the most likely number of successes is either $1$ or $2$—at any rate, *not* $0$.  We might guess (correctly, as it turns out, though you should demonstrate this yourself) that the critical value of $p$ is somewhere in between: specifically, when $P(0) = P(1)$.  That is, when

$$
\binom{3}{0}p^0(1-p)^{3-0} = \binom{3}{1}p^1(1-p)^{3-1}
$$

We can simplify this significantly first to

$$
(1-p)^3 = 3p(1-p)^2
$$

and then (providing we assume $p \not= 1$)

$$
1-p = 3p
$$

so the highest value of $p$ for which $0$ is a maximally likely outcome is $p = 1/4$.

The problem essentially asks you to generalize this line of analysis for any positive integer $n$ (instead of just the special case $n = 3$).